# Variável chamar outra

Tags: php, variáveis

Preciso declarar uma variável e chamar o nome de um objeto pelo código e também chamar o tipo. Tentei aninhar o `foreach` mas não deu certo. Tentei declarar a variável `$tipo` fora da função mas também não deu certo. Se eu apenas a chamar, da um erro

> Undefined index: tipo

Segue uma parte do código. Esse código é referente a uma tabela que exibe o nome, o tipo e dois botões para excluir e editar. Está tudo funcionando, só não sei como chamar o tipo para exibir corretamente as informações do banco de dados na tabela.

```
    echo '<table style="width:100%;border:2px solid #000000">';
    //echo '<th style="border:1px solid #000000; background-color:#3b8ccc">Código</th>';
    echo '<th style="border:1px solid #000000; background-color:#3b8ccc; width:55%">Local</th>';
    echo '<th style="border:1px solid #000000; background-color:#3b8ccc">Tipo</th>';
    echo '<th style="border:1px solid #000000; background-color:#3b8ccc">Ação</th>';


   // $tipo=  [];
    foreach ($repositorio as $codigo => $nome['nome'])
    {   
                echo '<tr>';
                //echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000">'.$codigo.'</td>';
                echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000">'.$nome['nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000">'.$tipo['tipo'].'</td>';

                echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000">';

                echo '<a href="index.php?r=a2d/excluiRepositorio&codobj='.$codigo.'"><i class="icon-remove" ></i> Excluir </a>';
                echo '<i class="icon-null" ></i>'; //icon-null para espaçar os botoes


                $this->widget('ext.popup.JPopupWindow');
                echo '<a href="index.php?r=a2d/editarRepositorio&codobj='.$codigo.'" title="editarRepositorios" class="editarRepositorios"><i class="icon-edit" ></i> Editar </a>';
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                            echo '$(".editarRepositorios").popupWindow({ 
                                  height:800, 
                                  width:1300, 
                                  top:50, 
                                  left:50 
                                  });'; 
                            echo '</script>';

                echo '</td>';

                echo '</tr>';        
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000">';
    echo '<textarea style="height:20px; width:50%; resize:none" name="NovoRepositorio"></textarea>';
    echo '</td>';

    echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;vertical-align:text-bottom;">'; 
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
                    array(
                        'buttonType' => 'submit',
                        'type' => 'success',
                        'icon' => 'icon-plus-sign',
                        'label' => 'Adicionar',                        
                        )
                  );
    echo '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';

    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: O que exatamente está/deveria estar na variável `$tipo`?

Comment: Você poderia nos dar um exemplo da estrutura da variável `$repositorio`? Acredito que seu `foreach` deveria ter esta estrutura `foreach ($repositorio as $codigo => $rep)` e a utilização dos índices `nome` e `tipo` desta forma `$rep['nome']` e `$rep['tipo']`, mas isto depende da estrutura da variável `$repositorio`.

Comment: Uma palavra. Exemplo: Na tabela tenho a informação "Antena" do tipo "Laboratório". Esse tipo deverá ser mostrado em uma caixinha para escolha, mas isso farei depois. O principal é conseguir chamar a informação no banco de dados.

Comment: public $repositorio = array();

Answer (score 1):

A montagem do seu código está confusa... como já foi apontado, não é correto usar a estrutura foreach da maneira como você está fazendo. Não sei exatamente qual a estrutura do objeto $repositorio, mas vou supor algo do tipo

```
$repositorio = [
    ['nome' => 'Nome 1', 'tipo' => 'Tipo 1'],
    ['nome' => 'Nome 2', 'tipo' => 'Tipo 2']
];
```

Se for o caso, seu foreach deveria ser

```
<?php foreach($repositorio as $item): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $item['nome'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['tipo'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Já se seu $repositorio for do tipo

```
$repositorio = [
   'Nome 1' => ['tipo' => 'Tipo 1'],
   'Nome 2' => ['tipo' => 'Tipo 2']
];
```

Você poderia montar assim:

```
<?php foreach($repositorio as $nome => $item): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $nome ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['tipo'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Se não for nada disso, explica melhor que tento ajudar. Abraços.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer desse jeito mas os itens na tabela não são exibidos corretamente. Até exibe alguma informação no "tipo" mas aparecem apenas letras ao invés do nome q deveria aparecer.

    `foreach ($repositorio as $codigo => $item)
        {   
                    echo '<tr>';
                    //echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000">'.$codigo.'</td>';
                    echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000">'.$item['nome'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000">'.$item['tipo'].'</td>';`

Comment: ps.: desculpa não estar formatado corretamente, ainda não sei como fazê-lo.

Answer (score 0):

para ser exibido algo nas variáveis $nome['nome'] e $tipo['tipo'] declaradas dentro do foreach
observe o bloco abaixo:

```
<?php
$tipo           = array("tipo" => "TIPO NO ARRAY");
$repositorio    = array("chave" => array("nome" => "NOME NO ARRAY"));
foreach ($repositorio as $codigo => $nome['nome'])
{
    echo 'NOME: '.$nome['nome']['nome'];    // imprime "NOME NO ARRAY"
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'TIPO: '.$tipo['tipo'];            // imprime "TIPO NO ARRAY"
}
?>
```

"Corrigindo" o trecho no foreach:

```
<?php
$tipo           = array("tipo" => "TIPO NO ARRAY");
$repositorio    = array("chave" => array("nome" => "NOME NO ARRAY"));
// foreach ($repositorio as $codigo => $nome['nome'])   // $nome['nome'] não parece correto :/
foreach ($repositorio as $codigo => $nome)
{
    // echo 'NOME: '.$nome['nome']['nome']; // imprime "NOME NO ARRAY", mas, observe abaixo :)
    echo 'NOME: '.$nome['nome'];    // imprime "NOME NO ARRAY"
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'TIPO: '.$tipo['tipo'];    // imprime "TIPO NO ARRAY"
}
?>
```

Sou pior do que péssimo para explicar, então, espero que você saiba analisar o codigo e entender onde esta se enganando, qualquer coisa, comente aqui que vou tentando te explicar...

Comment: apesar de parecer incorreto, se eu tirar o `['nome']` do `foreach ($repositorio as $codigo => $nome['nome'])`, a tabela não é exibida corretamente. Isso precisa fazer parte do código. Esse código é o padrão do projeto da empresa que eu estou fazendo estágio, então não posso alterar muita coisa =/

Comment: Não é pra alterar, é pra compreender o funcionamento... o "o quê estou acessando" da história..